# Zabbix Trapper: Cannot get data from orabbix

Tags: zabbix

I am using orabbix to monitor my db. The data from the queries executed on this db using orabbix are sent to zabbix server. However, I am not able to see the data reaching zabbix.

On my zabbix web console, I see this message on the triggers added - "Trigger expression updated. No status update so far."

Any ideas?

My update interval for the trigger is set to 30 sec.

Comment: Is your item Zabbix trapper item? Does it have anything in "Allowed hosts"? Is there any error message for this item? Would it be possible for you to show screenshots of your configuration? A DebugLevel=4 log will also show us how Zabbix reacts to traps received from Orabbix.

Comment: Yes it is zabbix trapper item. Where can I set allowed hosts and what should it value be?

Comment: From Orabbix logs, I see the following                                          2014-12-12 23:38:18,586 [pool-1-thread-86] DEBUG Orabbix - sending <req><host>V0ZDMURFVg==</host><key>V0ZDX0xFQUZfU1lTXzAwMg==</key><data>MA==</data></req>
 2014-12-12 23:38:18,587 [pool-1-thread-86] DEBUG Orabbix - received OK

Comment: Here are the images: http://i781.photobucket.com/albums/yy93/rishuoberoi/Untitled.png         http://i781.photobucket.com/albums/yy93/rishuoberoi/Untitled2.png

Comment: "Allowed hosts" field is present in trapper item configuration, below "Show value" field. If you wish to restrict the IPs that can send values for this item, "Allowed hosts" should contain these IPs (see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/trapper). Otherwise, it can be left empty.

Comment: Please have a look at the images above. I cannot upload here due to current profile point restrictions of minimum 10 points.

Comment: I shall make an answer based on the Orabbix XML and screenshots you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshots you posted, your host is named "wfc1dev1" and you have items with keys "WFC_WFS_SYS_001" and "WFC_WFS_SYS_002". However, based on the Orabbix XML that it sends to Zabbix, the hostname and item keys are different. Here is the XML:

```
<req><host>V0ZDMURFVg==</host><key>V0ZDX0xFQUZfU1lTXzAwMg==</key><data>MA==</dat‌​a></req>
```

From this, we can deduce the host:

```
$ echo V0ZDMURFVg== | base64 -d
WFC1DEV
```

The key:

```
$ echo V0ZDX0xFQUZfU1lTXzAwMg== | base64 -d
WFC_LEAF_SYS_002
```

The data:

```
$ echo MA== | base64 -d
0
```

It can be seen that neither the host name, nor item key match those configured on Zabbix server. Once you fix that, it should work.

Comment: This fixed it instantly. The hostname was incorrect. About the key, that was just an example. there are several other keys. thankyou so much!!!!!!